# How can one define the Selector in ardalis.Specification library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, specifications, specification-pattern, ardalis-specification

I am trying to utilize the [Ardalis.Specification](https://ardalis.github.io/Specification/) library to apply the specification pattern in my asp.net 6 project.

After installing the library, I created the following specification

```
public class ProductByIdsSpec : Specification<Product, ProductMenuItem>
{
    public ClientRecordByIdsSpec(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        if (ids == null || !ids.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        Query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));


        // some how I need to map Product to ProductMenuItem so only the needed columns are pulled from the database.
    }

}
```

Instead of pulling every value in `Product` from the database, I want to only pull the needed data by projecting the data to `ProductMenuItem`. The above specification is returning the following error

> SelectorNotFoundException Ardalis.Specification.SelectorNotFoundException: The specification must have Selector defined

How can I define the map between entity (i.e., `Product`) and and the result object (i.e., `ProductMenuItem`)?

I tried to add `Select()` definition but is giving me the same error

```
public class ProductByIdsSpec : Specification<Product, ProductMenuItem>
{
    public ClientRecordByIdsSpec(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        if (ids == null || !ids.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        Query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));


        Query.Select(x => new ProductMenuItem() { Name = x.Name, x.Id = x.Id });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProductByIdsSpec : Specification<Product, ProductMenuItem>
{
    public ClientRecordByIdsSpec(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Product, ProductMenuItem>> Selector { get; }
        = (product) => new ProductMenuItem();
}
```

You can override the Selector property in your Specification class and implement your projection there

https://github.com/ardalis/Specification/blob/main/Specification/src/Ardalis.Specification/Specification.cs#L29

Comment: You can not override Selector, cause it's not virtual

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this works for me. In the current implementation of the lib the `Selector` property is set via `ISpecificationBuilder` which is not at all obvious. I'd rather check [unit tests](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification/blob/main/Specification/tests/Ardalis.Specification.UnitTests/Fixture/Specs/StoreNamesSpec.cs) and code than docs.

```
public class ProductByIdsSpec : Specification<Product, ProductMenuItem>
{
    public ClientRecordByIdsSpec(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        if (ids == null || !ids.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        Query
            .Select(x => new ProductMenuItem() { Name = x.Name, x.Id = x.Id });
            .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
    }

}
```